# How do I write a list of lists to a file in python?

Tags: python, list

The code I have is this. I am trying to radix sort a list of numbers into a list of lists and then write that list of lists to a file, with each individual list on a different line. If I try to use `f.write`, it gives me a character buffer expected error.

```
from math import log

b = open("radix.in.txt").readlines()
a = [int(i) for i in b]

f = open("radix.out.txt", "w")
def getIndex(num, base, digit_num):
    return (num // base ** digit_num) % base  

def newLists(base):
    return [ [] for i in range(base) ]  

def order(q, base, digit_num):
    placehold = newLists(base)
    for num in a:
        placehold[getIndex(num, base, digit_num)].append(num)  
    return placehold

def radixSort(a, base):
    passes = 3
    new_list = a
    for digit_num in range(passes):
    new_list = order(new_list, base, digit_num)
    list_c = [str(i) for i in new_list]
    print list_c


radixSort(a, 10)
```

Putting f.write(list_c) in after the print list_c gives this traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Nolan Caldwell\Desktop\HW5.py", line 29, in <module>
    radixSort(a, 10)
  File "C:\Users\Nolan Caldwell\Desktop\HW5.py", line 26, in radixSort
    f.write(list_c)
TypeError: expected a character buffer object
```

Comment: Can you post the full error?

Answer (score 3):

`list_c` is a `list`-of-`str`. To convert that to a single `str`, use `str.join()`:

```
f.write('\n'.join(list_c)+'\n')
```

Or, if you prefer, you can write each `str` individually:

```
for s in list_c:
  f.write(s+'\n')
```

Comment: Both of these are just creating an empty text file.

Comment: @NolanCaldwell - With all due respect, I don't believe you. The first one *can't* produce an empty text file -- it will always print at least one blank line. Further, when I test these, they produce output files with 10 lines, the contents of which depend upon the input given. Perhaps the lines you add aren't being executed?

Comment: I totally believe that it should work. I am stumped as to why it doesn't. I added the code you supplied to the radixSort method before the print statement which would surely execute them, no? For both of your code samples, a text file named "radix.out.txt" is created but nothing(it could be an empty line) is in the file.

Comment: There are two possibilities: you write to the wrong file, foo.txt, thinking that you wrote to bar.txt (less likely), or your list is empty (most likely). That means `list_c` is empty, thus `new_list` is empty, which means `order()` returned an empty list. Investigate your code from there.

Answer (score 0):

convert it to a string and use literal_eval to get it as an array while reading

```
f=open('file.txt','w')
a=[[1,2],[3,4],[4,5]]
b=str(a)
f.write(b)
```

and when you read,

```
import ast
f=open('file.txt','r')
a=f.read()
b=ast.literal_eval(a)
```

because the `write()` function can process only strings. Or convert the list of lists to a string and use write.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it is a great chance to use `csv` module.

```
import csv
with open('numbers.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    for lst in list_of_lists:
        writer.writerow(lst)
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, you need to serialize the data in some way before you can write it to a file. You can pickle, json encode, xml encode, stick it in a database like sqlite, write it line by line, put it in a CSV file, and etc... The "best" method (there is no best) depends on what you plan to do with that file later. Do people need to read it? Do non-python programs need to read it? Is it large enough to be concerned about the amount of space it takes?

If you just want to save a list of integers and want it to be readable in many programming languages, I like json

```
import json
(... your other stuff here...)
new_list = order(new_list, base, digit_num)
json.dump(new_list, open('myfile.json', 'w'))
```